# JQuery tabSlideOut not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabslideout

```
  $(document).ready(function () {  
    $(function(){   
          $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({  
             tabHandle: '.handle',                               
             pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif',          
             imageHeight: '122px',                               
             imageWidth: '40px',                                  
             tabLocation: 'left',                               
             speed: 300,                                          
             action: 'click',                                     
             topPos: '200px',                                    
             fixedPosition: false                                 
         });
     });
});
```

tabslideout works perfectly i tried to hide after some time interval when the slide is show i used

```
 setTimeout(function(){---},3000)
```

it hide, but when i click it again to open it hide again instantly

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.slide-out-div').delay(3000).slideUp('fast');
```